# How to create condition based multiple filter and return non boolean?

Tags: java

Trying to apply multiple  filters based on condition, pseudo code is:

```
if TypeA exception 
    then throw TypeA Exception
if TypeB 
    then throw TypeB Exception
else TypeC Exception.
```

I don't know how to do it using filters based on condition:

```
List<InvalidArgumentException> invalidEx = e.getInvalidException();
return invalidEx.stream()
       .filter (ic -> {
if(ic.getInvalidExcepType().equals(ExceptionType.TypeA)) {
 return (RuntimeException) new TypeAException(e);
} else if (ic.getInvalidExcepType().equals(ExceptionType.TypeB))
 return (RuntimeException) new TypeBException(e);
}).orElse (new TypeCException(e));
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `map` instead of `filter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `filter`, which just returns all the elements in the `Stream` that match the given predicate, you need to use `map`:

```
return invalidEx.stream()
   .map(ic -> {
          if(ic.getInvalidExcepType().equals(ExceptionType.TypeA)) {
              return (RuntimeException) new TypeAException(e);
          } else if (ic.getInvalidExcepType().equals(ExceptionType.TypeB)) {
              return (RuntimeException) new TypeBException(e);
          } else {
              return new TypeCException(e);
          }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(Or some other terminal operation)

Comment: You are right but this does not answer the question. I mean, it will probably work, but I think he is trying to find a way to simplify the if-else chain.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, you want to use map instead of filter, on the other hand if you have a lot of possible ExceptionTypes and want to create something that resolves them without a really long chain of ifs, I believe you could create something like this.

```
class ExceptionResolver {
    private static Map<ExceptionType, Function<InvalidArgumentException, RuntimeException>> exceptionMapping = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        exceptionMapping.put(ExceptionType.TypeA, TypeAException::new);
        exceptionMapping.put(ExceptionType.TypeB, TypeBException::new);
    }

    static RuntimeException resolveException(ExceptionType type, InvalidArgumentException e) {
        return exceptionMapping.get(type).apply(e);
    }
}
```

And then use it like this

```
List<InvalidArgumentException> invalidEx = e.getInvalidException();
        return invalidEx.stream()
                .map(f -> ExceptionResolver.resolveException(f.getInvalidExceptionType(), f));
```